# Can .NET code compiled with the unsafe tag run in Mono?

Tags: .net, mono, bitmap, unsafe

I have some code that does Bitmap manipulation using the LockBits method and accessing the bitmap data directly using a pointer.  This code has to be wrapped in an unsafe block, of course, and I was wondering if this means that the code would not work in Mono.

I'm assuming the Bitmap class is available in Mono, but maybe that's another deal-breaker.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it can, and Mono has the Bitmap class.

Answer (score 9):

Yes. Here's the Mono documentaiton on the unsafe keyword: http://go-mono.org/docs/index.aspx?link=ecmaspec%3A25

The Bitmap class is available as well. You can find the documentation here: http://go-mono.org/docs/index.aspx?tlink=35@ecma%3a1990%23Bitmap%2f. Just like in .NET Bitmaps inherits Image, which is nice.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `unsafe` is available.

Mono even uses the `unsafe` keyword internally to try to speed up in some areas, such as `BigInteger` arithmetic in `Mono.Security`.